# Diffable Data Source in addition to older implementation

Tags: ios, diffabledatasource

Is it possible to use the diffable data source in addition to supporting the older implementations for the lower ios versions.

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/ra1028/DiffableDataSources in two projects. It's pretty similar to Apple's implementation.

Comment: Sure @vadian will check it out. Also was actually thinking more on the lines of supporting the older versions with the older code and using diffable for newer versions; the diffable code eventually replacing the older.

Comment: Use `#available` for conditional compiling.